# Why when i try run this code in reactjs, its always output wrong total number

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i still newbie in reactjs, and i try to build a some project. this project its to display any product price and stock, but here this problem.

i try to sum this number to get a total price in my product in reactjs, but the output always like this. how to fix that...

```js
import React from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import calc from "./calc";

export default class TableData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let arr = []
    const {
      data,
    } = this.props;
    
    const {
      location, proformaItem,
    } = data;

    proformaItem.forEach((item) => {
      const parseStock = JSON.parse(item.product_stock);
      parseStock.forEach((stock) => {
        let total = 0
        if (stock[1] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[1]);
        }
        if (stock[5] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[5])
        }

        arr.push(total);
      })
    })

    console.log(arr);

    return (
      <>
        {
          proformaItem.map((item, index) => {
            const parseStock = JSON.parse(item.product_stock);
            const parseItem = JSON.parse(item.items);

            return (
              <tr key={nanoid(12)}>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{parseStock.map((key) => key[1])}</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{parseStock.map((key) => key[3])}</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{parseStock.map((key) => key[5])}</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{item.categoryDescription}</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{item.productDescription}</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{
                  parseStock.map((item) => {
                    if (item[1] !== undefined && item[5] !== undefined) {
                      console.log(calc(item[1], item[5]));
                    }
                  })
                }
                </td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>1</td>
                <td key={nanoid(12)}>{parseItem.map((key) => key['qty'])}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

here's my data in json

```js
{
    "proformaItem": [
        {
            "product_id": "1852",
            "productDescription": "Charcoal Size M",
            "categoryDescription": "7200 Premium Tee",
            "product_stock": "[{\"1\": 272}, {\"3\": 5328}, {\"5\": 177}]",
            "items": "[{\"qty\": 1, \"productId\": 1852, \"proformaInfoId\": 556745, \"proformaItemId\": 2679283}]"
        },
        {
            "product_id": "1801",
            "productDescription": "Black Size S",
            "categoryDescription": "7200 Premium Tee",
            "product_stock": "[{\"1\": 745}, {\"3\": 30744}, {\"5\": 273}]",
            "items": "[{\"qty\": 1, \"productId\": 1801, \"proformaInfoId\": 556745, \"proformaItemId\": 2679284}]"
        },
    ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsUU2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you changing `arr` array in the render method, it means it pushes every time the component renders, that's why you are getting unstable results. To avoid this, you could move this logic

```
proformaItem.forEach((item) => {
      const parseStock = JSON.parse(item.product_stock);
      parseStock.forEach((stock) => {
        let total = 0
        if (stock[1] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[1]);
        }
        if (stock[5] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[5])
        }

        arr.push(total);
      })
    })
```

to `componentDidMount()` callback, for example.

Also you shouldn't use `key={nanoid(12)}`, because it creates the new keys every time it renders, but key should be strong and stable. It's better to use your product it: `key={item.product_id}`

UPD: if you want just to sum up your total, you don't need to use `arr` at all, you could use just `total`:

```
let total = 0
proformaItem.forEach((item) => {
      const parseStock = JSON.parse(item.product_stock);
      parseStock.forEach((stock) => {
        if (stock[1] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[1]);
        }
        if (stock[5] !== undefined) {
          total += Number(stock[5])
        }
      })
    })

console.log(total)
```

Comment: sorry i still got error, and still same like my picture (the number are separate), the number should have been accommodated first in the total variable, but instead it was not accommodated and the number is pushed every time the forEach() function is executed